# Does leader election need to be executed in separate step after setting up 3-machine ensemble?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I currently have 3 machines in a Zookeeper ensemble - I've already set up the configuration file, and the 3 machines in the ensemble can communicate with each other.

What exactly is leader election? Do I need to use a LeaderLatch to start leader election, or does it happen automatically after correctly setting up the configuration file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit confusing because the Zookeeper server itself has the concept of a leader that it takes care of electing when you set up a ZK ensemble.  But that leader is purely internal to ZK.  See [this post](http://www.sleberknight.com/blog/sleberkn/entry/distributed_coordination_with_zookeeper_part3) for more details.

If you want leader election for your application then you will need to implement a leader election recipe, either using something like Curator LeaderLatch or rolling your own based on [the recipe on the ZK site](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection).